# How to safely store passwords on Android?

Tags: java, android, cryptography, passwords, password-encryption

The task is to save the entered password(PasswordStr) or mKey.getEncoded byte[] and later automatically send to the Crypto API (Cipher)

```
    SecretKey mKey = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1").generateSecret(new PBEKeySpec(PasswordStr.toCharArray());
```

It is clear that this password can also be encrypted , but this will require another password and so on to infinity.

May be Android already provides a mechanism for storing passwords?

p.s use remote server is not possible. Need to be stored locally.

Comment: What is your use case? Why do you need to store a password or a key at all? Currently it is not clear if you want to store a password or a key. Given the choice, do save the generated *key* (and the public salt of course). You don't want to leak the user's password to other parties!

Comment: It would be ideal to store the string password.
But given the vulnerability of Java code in principle it doesn't matter.

I want to make sure my users the security of their data.
Salt, iteration, etc can be seen after decompilation.

Comment: Now it even makes less sense. The salt should not be in the code, a salt should be random, not [this kind of random](http://xkcd.com/221/). The salt and iteration count can be public.

Comment: Maybe I don't have much knowledge in the science of cryptography.
But what's the point of having a public salt?
Or the use of salt increases the password cracking time and only?

If so , it makes more sense to store the Password, and not SecretKey

Comment: The salt is used to make sure that rainbow tables cannot be created and to make sure that you cannot find out that two persons (or the same person for different situations) reused the password, leading to the same password hash. Therefore it can be public without issue. It is sometimes expanded with a static/secret salt called a pepper, but the salt would still be required. Don't store the password; people may reuse passwords, so you would be responsible for the damage if the password somehow leaks out.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Android's `Keystore API`.

A secret is encrypted by a masterpassword derived from the phone's password or pin. It is regarded as a good software based encryption solution. Note, that the user must set a password/pin on his phone for this to work.

[Nelenkov gives a good overview:](http://nelenkov.blogspot.de/2012/05/storing-application-secrets-in-androids.html)

> Android's credential storage is implemented as a native Linux service
>   (daemon), with a few extra layers on top of it that make it available
>   to the framework. Let's quickly review what we know about the keystore
>   daemon (described in more detail here):
>
> - it's a native daemon, started at boot
> - it provides a local control socket to allow apps and system services to talk to it
> - it encrypts keys using an AES 128 bit master
> - key encrypted keys are stored in /data/misc/keystore, one file per key
> - the master key is derived from the device unlock password or PIN it
> - authorizes administration commands execution and key access based on caller UID

See the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore.html) for more details.

Comment: I'm downvoting this as I don't think this will solve the question. The question was to securely store a password, not a secret key. Using a platform keystore *is* a good idea in general, but it needs to be supplemented with an example on how to store passwords with it.

Comment: In your example you are referring to a secret key, so I thought this would be a viable solution for you. You can of course use the key to encrypt a password (or anything else) and this will get you out of the password cycle ("... but this will require another password and so on to infinity.")

Comment: Well, I thought this was asked for, but now I'm getting confused. Revoked downvote, asked org. poster for clarification in comments.

Comment: Upvoted now instead. You should store the derived key or secret, not the password (if anything needs to be stored at all). That does however mean that you also have to store the salt somewhere.

Comment: "the master key is derived from the device unlock password or PIN it"
What if the user has not set a PIN on the system? The KeyStore will not work? Somehow it's not good

Answer (score 2):

Check [Handling Credentials section on the android developers guide](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html). I'll quote it here.

Where possible, username and password should not be stored on the device. Instead, perform initial authentication using the username and password supplied by the user, and then use a **short-lived**, service-specific **authorization token**.

Services that will be accessible to multiple applications should be accessed using [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html). If possible, use the [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) class to invoke a cloud-based service and do not store passwords on the device.

After using [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) to retrieve an [Account](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html), [CREATOR](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/Account.html#CREATOR) before passing in any credentials, so that you do not inadvertently pass credentials to the wrong application.

If credentials are to be used only by applications that you create, then you can verify the application which accesses the AccountManager using [checkSignature()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#checkSignatures(int,%20int)). Alternatively, if only one application will use the credential, you might use a [KeyStore](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/security/KeyStore.html) for storage.

Comment: This is all correct, but sometimes there are valid use cases for storing passwords (i.e. for 3rd party services), and this answer does not address those.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `SQLCipher` for android. It is an extension of `SQLite` that provides transparent 256-bit AES encryption of database files

Comment: Without any more security details this answer is not as strong as it could be. AES-256 actually says nothing at all about the level of security provided.